# Behaviour of scanf when newline is in the format string

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, counter

Below is the copy of my code. Basically, I need to create a program that calculates pay based on "paycodes" eg the worker's position. I've created my switch statement and everything works except for the very beginning when I'm entering the first paycode. I enter the first paycode, it goes to the next line, leaving it blank. I put in another number, and it runs that number and the previous number the way it is supposed to. Then, after that everything works fine. I'm sure it's a simple solution but it is being a bit tricky for me. Also, I'm not sure exactly how I'm supposed to format my code on here to make it look like it does on the server, so I apologize for the confusing way it looks.

```
#include <stdio.h> //precompiled header
int main(void)
{
    //declare variables
    unsigned int counter = 0; //counters to calculate amount of workers paid
    unsigned int counter2 = 0;
    unsigned int counter3 = 0;
    unsigned int counter4 = 0;

    int paycode;
    float overtime; //amount of overtime hours
    float salary; //weekly salary
    float hoursWorked;
    float hourlyRate;
    float grossWeeklySales; //weekly sales for commissioned workers
    int itemsProduced;
    float fixedAmount; //money given per item produced

    //prompt for input
    printf("Please enter the employee's paycode.\n");
    printf("1: Manager\n");
    printf("2: Hourly Worker\n");
    printf("3: Commission Worker\n");
    printf("4: Pieceworker\n");
    printf("-1 to end\n");
    printf("%s","Paycode: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &paycode);

    while (paycode != -1)//begin while loop
    {
        switch(paycode)
        {
        case 1: //calculate manager's pay
            printf("Manager selected.\n");        
            printf("Enter weekly salary: $ ");
            scanf("%f", &salary);
            counter = counter + 1;
            printf("Weekly salary is %.2f\n\n", salary);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Hourly worker selected.\n");        
            printf("Enter hourly rate: $");
            scanf("%f", &hourlyRate);
            printf("Enter hours worked: ");
            scanf("%f", &hoursWorked);
            if(hoursWorked<=40) //if statement to calculate overtime
            {
                salary=hourlyRate*hoursWorked;
                printf("No overtime worked.");
            }
            else
            {
                salary=40.0*hourlyRate+(hoursWorked-40)*1.5*hourlyRate;
                overtime = hoursWorked - 40;
                printf("Total amount of overtime worked: %.2f\n", overtime);
            }
            counter2 = counter2 +1;        
            printf("Weekly salary is: $%.2f\n\n", salary); 
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Commissioned worker selected.\n");        
            printf("Enter gross weekly sales: $");
            scanf("%f", &grossWeeklySales);
            salary=.057*grossWeeklySales+250;
            counter3 = counter3 +1;
            printf("Weekly salary is: $%.2f\n\n", salary);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Pieceworker Selected.\n");        
            printf("Enter amount of items produced: ");
            scanf("%d", &itemsProduced);
            printf("Enter the fixed pay per item produced: $ ");
            scanf("%f", &fixedAmount);
            salary=itemsProduced*fixedAmount;
            counter4 = counter4 + 1;
            printf("Weekly salary is: $%.2f\n\n", salary);
        }
        //get next input
        printf("Please enter paycode, -1 to end.\n");
        printf("%s","Paycode: ");
        scanf("%d", &paycode);    
    }
    printf("Number of managers paid: %d\n", counter); //display amount of workers paid
    printf("Number of hourly workers paid is: %d\n", counter2);
    printf("Number of commisioned workers is: %d\n", counter3);
    printf("Number of piece workers paid is: %d\n\n", counter4);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `'\n'` character in the format string of `scanf("%d\n", &paycode)` matches any number of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline etc. - characters for which the `isspace` function declared in `ctype.h` yields true) in the input given. Therefore, the `scanf` call will read and discard any number of whitespace characters till it encounters a non-whitespace character at which point it will return. This is true for any whitespace character in the format string of `scanf` and not only the newline character. For example, the following will exhibit the same behaviour:

```
scanf("%d ", &paycode)
         ^ a space
```

You should change your `scanf` call to

```
scanf("%d", &paycode);
```

Also, instead of  `printf("%s", "Paycode: ");`  you can simply write `printf("Paycode: ");`
You have commented that `stdio.h` is a *precompiled* header. It's not. It's a header file which contains macro definitions and function declarations or prototypes. It's not an object file in the sense of being *precompiled*.

Answer (score 3):

The function `scanf` receives as a parameter the format it expects from you. By passing `scanf("%d\n", &paycode);` you're saying "Hey, computer, read a number AND a newline, and save it in the `paycode` variable". Additionally, `scanf` will read and ignore white space characters.

Try changing it to `scanf("%d", &paycode);`, so you the computer only reads and saves the number.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Comment: not just a newline but any number of whitespace characters. `scanf` will not return until it meets a non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
scanf("%d\n", &paycode);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &paycode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d\n", &paycode);
         ^^ Scanf is waiting for this newline to come.
```

Change it to:

```
scanf("%d", &paycode);
```

Answer (score 0):

The newline constant is confusing matters here. You need to change the first

scanf("%d\n", &paycode);

to

scanf("%d", &paycode);